# C++ Socket retrieve and send encrypted Data

Tags: c++, file, sockets, binary, blowfish

I got a small problem.. Currently im writing a small tool which connects to a Server, downloads some blowfish encrypted Data into a `char Array` `(char buffer[512])` and saves that Array into a file `(fstream ios::binary)`.

Then later i reopen that file `(ifstream ios::binary)` and send it back. This time i read it into a `std::string` and not a `char[]`.

My Problem now is that the Data is corrupted after i send them back.

What would be the best way to acomblish this? Is it safe to use `char[]` and `std::string`? Or does that somehow corrupt the data? (i guess so).

**If you need some code examples i can provide them.**

Thanks!

**##########################**

Okay a quick update to give you more details.

Im writing a Tool for a game (on OS X), its seperated in two parts:

1. Retrieve the encrypted Data from Game Servers and save them.
2. Send the saved encrypted Data back to the local Game

Problem: When the saved Data arrives the local Game, the Game just spits out that the Data cant be decrypted => data corruption.

Here's the code for 1. (Its just poc for selftesting purpose):

```
mode == 0 => no gameDataChunk there
mode == 1 => gameDataChunk there, need to write
mode == 2 => keyFrame there
*/
std::string socketRead(int socket, int mode, std::string num_chunk, std::string num_key, std::string game_id){

std::string response = "";

char buffer[512];

int bytes;

while((bytes = read(socket, buffer, 511)) > 0){

    std::string temp(buffer, bytes);

    //std::cout << temp;

    response = response + temp;

    if(!(temp.find("HTTP/1.1 200")<1800000)){
        if(temp.find("HTTP/1.1")<1800000){
            std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "GOT NOT A 200 !!!" << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << temp << std::endl << std::endl;
            return "EXIT";
        }
    }

    if(mode == 1){
        if(temp.find("\r\n\r\n")<1800000){
            write_gameDataChunk(buffer, 1, temp.find("\r\n\r\n")+4, num_chunk, game_id);
        }
        else{
            write_gameDataChunk(buffer, 0, 0, num_chunk, game_id);
        }
    }
    else if(mode == 2){
        if(temp.find("\r\n\r\n")<1800000){
            write_keyFrame(buffer, 1, temp.find("\r\n\r\n")+4, num_key, game_id);
        }
        else{
            write_keyFrame(buffer, 0,0, num_key, game_id);
        }
    }

    bzero(buffer, 512);

}

return response;

}

void write_gameDataChunk(char buffer[], int mode, int index, std::string num, std::string game_id){

std::fstream write;

char local_buffer[512];

if(mode == 0){
    //complete bin data

    write.open("/tmp/" + game_id + "/" + num + "/game_dataChunk.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);

    write << buffer;

}
else if(mode == 1){
    //partial bin data

    std::string command = "mkdir /tmp/" + game_id + "/" + num;
    std::system(command.c_str());

    write.open("/tmp/" + game_id + "/" + num + "/game_dataChunk.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    strcpy(local_buffer, buffer+index);

    write << local_buffer;

}

write.close();

}
```

Here is the code for 2.:

```
std::string get_DataChunk(std::string game_id, int chunkId){

std::ifstream read;

std::string dummy;
std::string command;
std::string result = "";

command = "/tmp/" + game_id + "/" + std::to_string(chunkId) + "/game_dataChunk.bin";

read.open(command.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

while(getline(read,dummy)){

    result = result + dummy;

}

read.close();

return result;

}
```

This is all testing code for myself and not finished, so its kinda ugly... but i hope you will understand what i mean. I did not often had to deal with binary Data send over Sockets..

Comment: `std::string` does not corrupt the data, and is safe to use with binary data, assuming you don't expect `null` termination.

Comment: First of all, ios::binary is **not** cross-platform. You need to make sure it's not the case.
And how do you check data corruption?

Comment: @Ternvein "ios::binary is not cross-platform" What would the meaning of this statement be? The name `std::ios::binary` and its meaning are defined by the standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940846/binary-files-and-cross-platform-compatability

Comment: @Ternvein this has nothing to do with `std::ios::binary` which has a very specific, well-defined meaning. It is not even mentioned in that question or any of the answers. So what's your case against `std::ios::binary`?

Comment: @n.m.
Regarding this specific question my case is about writing a binary file with data received from the remote server.
You can surely do this, but there are many considerations about it. So, if you write a binary file containing a simple `int` value on, for example, i386 and then read it with the same algorithm on mips32, those data are surely will not be the same.
Which leads us to my other question about ways to check data validity.

Comment: @Ternvein If you want to say "values of arbitrary data types written as-is to a stream are not necessarily readable on other platforms", you are welcome to say so, because it's true. `std::ios::binary` has nothing to do with it though.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not meant to deal with binary. It is meant to deal with strings.

What you want is a `std::vector<char>` which doesn't care about what values you are storing.

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing in `std::string` that prevents it from working with binary data.

Comment: I just dont know from where the corrupgion comes.. If its not a std::string based error, maybe its because of this: When writing the encrypted Data i write the whole char[] buffer even if its not completely filled. Is a char buffer[512] filling up the free space with something when only the first 100 chars are filled?
Or does fstream manipulate the written data?

Comment: Ok, I think you should update your question to show us a little more code !

Comment: I'll do so when im back home

Answer (score 0):

Any '\0' in your binary data will stop construct the std::string. So the std::string().size() only count to the character before 1st '\0'. Use std::vector<unsigned char> instead.

By the way, what does 1800000 mean? I know that `HTTP/1.1 200` is the characters you received at the earliest.(poor english)

Comment: Okay ty will try that with the vectors. std::string.find() returns > 1800000 when the string does not match, thus when the result is below that ive got a match

Comment: "Any '\0' in your binary data will stop construct the std::string". Not really. `std::string` can contain embedded NUL characters just fine. "std::string().size() only count to the character before 1st '\0'". Again not true.

Comment: So wheres my fault then?

Comment: @n.m. `std::string str("abc\0abc"); std::cout<< str.size();` what's it?

Comment: You didn't specify the length. If you want to claim that `string temp(buffer, bytes)` will stop at a null byte, you ought to demonstrate it for this form of initialization.

Comment: @n.m. my bad, it's not the same ctor mentioned by question author. sorry. :-)

Comment: Do i somewhere in my code stop to copy the data at a '\0' ? Or is my fault in the 2. part?..

Comment: guys common... i really need this one.

Comment: @EzraKnobloch and, why you use std::getline on .bin file ? It's only for text file, not binary. (here your blowfish-ed data are not text).

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer i was searching for, will try that later.

Comment: read() and write() did solve the issue with the '\0', but i still got somehow currupted data. Guessing it has something to do with the network packet format.